# How can I prevent the Night Light ones from exploding?

Tags: hammerfight

In Chapter 1, Part 3, Section 2 of Hammerfight I now get to face the "Night Lights"/"Light Ones", who have the poor habit of exploding, taking an awful lot of my health in the process. Obviously, I can't ignore them, or they'll just asplode Chief Sayadi instead.

How can I safely handle explosives in Hammerfight?

Comment: I barely passed the level now, but I was lucky because I got only a couple of those damn things in the level that time around.

Comment: A good tactic for this level is just to KEEP RUNNING! Let them attack your partner when possible, but keep passing back and forth over the balloon so they the wasps target you and not the worm. Then just pick them off when it's safe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To kill the Night Lights, you should avoid hitting the abdomen at all cost. Aim for the head, and try to hit them with a slashing motion rather than hitting them straight, damaging the abdomen trough their head. You can kill them by hitting the abdomen without explosion if you are careful, but this is more difficult and dangerous.

For explosives in general, you should be gentle if you want to deflect them or send them back. Don't hit at full speed and straight on, rather try to make them rebound on you blade or catch them in a flail before flinging them away. Explosives can explode before the end of their time if hit too hard.